# Pointer to a string and the difference between assignment and dereferencing

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf

In the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char* message = "Hello C Programmer!";
    printf("%s", message);

    return 0;
}
```

I don't fully understand why it wasn't necessary to prepend an `'*'` to message in the `printf` call. I was under the assumption that `message`, since it is a pointer to a `char`, the first letter in the double quoted string, would display the *address* of the `'H'`.

Comment: To display address you need to use `%p` and not `%s`.

Comment: `%s` is making `printf` to *expect* a pointer to `char`. So it wasn't "not necessary" it was necessary no to.

Comment: add a "*" and you might have a good segmentation fault. %s requires an address of a string terminated by '\0'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%s` format operator requires its corresponding argument to be a `char *` pointer. It prints the entire string that begins at that address. A string is a sequence of characters ending with a null byte. That's why this prints the entire message.

If you supply an array as the corresponding argument, it's automatically converted to a pointer to the first character of the array. In general, whenever an array is used as an r-value, it undergoes this conversion.

You don't need to use the `*` operator because the argument is supposed to be a pointer. If you used `*message` you would only pass the `'H'` character to `printf()`. You would do this if you were using the `%c` format instead of `%s` -- its corresponding argument should be a `char`.

Comment: int printf (constant char * restrict format, ... ) The printf function expects a pointer and the initial/beginning address of the double quoted string was assigned to it?

Comment: A double quoted string becomes a pointer to the first character when used as an r-value.

Comment: Just like in your initialization of the `message` variable. It sets the variable to the address of the `H` character.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that `message` is a pointer, of type "pointer to `char`", or `char *`.  So *if* you were trying to print a character (an individual character), you would certainly have needed a `*`:

```
printf("first character: %c\n", *message);
```

In a printf format specifier, `%c` expects a character, which is what `*message` gives you.

But you weren't trying to print a single character, you were trying to print the whole string.  And in a printf format specifier, `%s` expects a *pointer* to a character, the first of usually several characters to print.  So

```
printf("entire string: %s\n", message);
```

is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion specifier `%s` is used to output strings (a sequence of characters terminated with the zero character `'\0'`) pointers to first characters of which are passed to the function printf as an argument.

You can imagine that the function internally executes the following loop

```
for ( ; *message != '\0'; ++message )
{
    printf( "%c", *message );
}
```

If you will supply the expression `*message` then it has type `char` and the function printf will try to interpret its value that is character `'H'` as a value of a pointer. As result the function call will have undefined behavior.

To output the value of the pointer `message`  you should use the conversion specifier `%p` like

```
printf( "%p", message );
```

Or as an integer value as for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *message = "Hello C Programmer!";

    printf( "The value of the pointer message is %" PRIiPTR "\n", ( intptr_t )message );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, a pointer must be used here.

If you passed a character, it would be passed by value, and `printf` would lose the original address of the character. That means it would no longer be possible to access the characters that come after the first.

You need to pass a pointer by value to ensure you're retaining the original address of the head of the string.